# Refresh (reload) NSManagedObject after failed validation

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I've added maximum / minimum validation rules for attributes in `.xcdatamodel` like so:

[image: validation rules]

Then if I set invalid value and try to save like so, it fails as I'd expect:

```
object.rating = 100
try? AppDelegate.context.save()
```

But then when I re-fetch the object from context it would still contain invalid `.rating`, not the one before validation (the one that is still in datastore).

If I restart the app, then the object's `rating` would be the old valid value. How do I have `managedObjectContext` refresh to value from datastore after failed save attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this:

```
managedObjectContext.refresh(managedObject, false)
```

It have to refresh object in managed object context.
Also, you can use:

```
managedObjectContext.reset()
```

It will reset all managedObjects in context without saving.